# dotnet test logger html: Show all executed tests, not just the ones that failed

Tags: testing, .net-core, xunit

I am looking for a way to get a formated html file from my xUnit test cases.
At the moment, I use `dotnet test -l:html` which is almost what I want. Unfortunately, it only shows failed test cases - but I would like it to show all test cases.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Just as a side note: I am not interested in code coverage reports.